# upload file in flask not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_file_uploading.htm) but am unable to get a file to upload to the directory I want. It says it was succesful, but the file is not in the directory it's supposed to be.

Update I changed my views.py to try and fix the directory call but now I get this error:

```
File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py", line 33, in uploader
 f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),secure_filename(f.filename))
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/uploads'
```

views.py

```
@app.route('/mobility_import_html')
@login_required
def mobility_import_html():
   return render_template('mobility_import_html.html')


@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      #f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']),secure_filename(f.filename))
      print("f.filename", f.filename)
      return 'success'
```

mobility_import_html.html

```
{% extends "mobility.html" %}

{% block mobility %}
      <form action ="{{ url_for('uploader') }}" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_babel import Babel, lazy_gettext
from config import basedir, ADMINS, MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USERNAME, \
MAIL_PASSWORD
from .momentjs import momentjs

app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads')
```

Comment: "It says" what says? Take a look at [ask]

Comment: You should link to the tutorial, but I do not see opening file for saving.

Comment: Sorry about that, I must not have pasted the link properly. It is posted now.

Answer (score 1):

Your save line should be something like:

```
f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],secure_filename(f.filename))
```